# Big O notation- having hard time proving it

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I need to prove **t(n) is O(n!)**

```
if t(n) = (n!)(n-1)
```

this is the formula I'm working with? any suggestions?

```
(n!)(n-1) <= c(n!)
```

I'm having a hard time proving this

would this formula work instead?

```
(n!)(n-1) <= c(n * n!)
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't O(n!). You have the right equation that would need to be true if n!(n-1) = O(n!):

```
n!(n-1) <= cn!
```

But then dividing both sides by n! gives:

```
n-1 <= c
```

There's no constant c that's greater than all positive integers, so you have a contradiction.

Comment: What happens if I change the solution to (n-1)(n!) <= c(n*n!)? Would that make sense?